# How to pass arguments to exec() in python

Tags: python, arguments, exec

I have converted my python script into exe using `pyinstaller`. This exe needs to call another python script. Now `pyinstaller` binds the python interpreter so we can call any other python script like below:

```
exec(open('external_script.py').read())
```

This will execute `external_script.py`. I want to perform `external_script.py install` using exec. So I also want to pass `install` as an argument. Something like below:

```
exec(open('external_script.py').read(), {'install'})
```

In above line of code, I am passing install as argument. But here I am not sure if this is correct syntax or not. Can anyone please tell me how can we pass arguments in exec python. Thanks

Comment: i think executing a file can be done differently . Let me check it and tell later

Answer (score 3):

to pass arguments to `exec()` you need to pass `dict` as an argument for globals/locals not `set`.

```py
exec(open('external_script.py'.read(),{'argv':'install'})
```

and it will create `argv` reference inside `exec()` scope, if you pass array to your `external_script.py` you will have to do add the following to the code

```
for i in argv: sys.argv.append(i)
```

note: if you use `from sys import argv` to import argv it will overwrite the value you passed with `['external_script.py']`

Answer (score 1):

**`os.system` is used to execute a cmd command**

```
import os

cmd=input("type a  cmd statement here")
try:
    exec(os.system(cmd))
except Exception as e:
    print(e)
```

For you it will be

```
exec(os.system("external_script.py install"))
```

Comment: `os.system` alone executes a script. Why do you suggest `exec()` around that?